# Django form imageupload give empty dic

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to create edit profile form, in which i am trying to data from edit profile form. i am getting all data in request.POST but i am getting empty {} using request.Files

view.py

```
class EditProfile(View):
    template_name="todo_app/edit_profile.html"
    def get(self,request,pk):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_id=pk
            profile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_id)
            content={
                'profile':profile,
            }
            return render(request,self.template_name,content)
        else:
            return redirect('todo_app:login')
    
    def post(self,request,pk):
        request_data=request.POST
        first_name=request_data.get('first_name')
        last_name=request_data.get('last_name')
        mob_no=request_data.get('mob_no')
        address_1=request_data.get('address_1')
        address_2=request_data.get('address_2')
        gender=request_data.get('gender')
        age=request_data.get('age')
        state=request_data.get('state')
        city=request_data.get('city')
        country=request_data.get('country')
        bio=request_data.get('bio')
        # profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']
        print(request_data)
        print("_"*123)
        print(request.FILES)
        return redirect('todo_app:edit_profile',pk)
```

and print result on console is

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['mkfuwR6Uc99svosQvsVpho11JOXOdESSmp2sm1ULDFrFu3UHRrkASTWeSyRwXyzH'], 'first_name': ['upasana'], 'last_name': ['kulshresths'], 'address_1': ['9 Purushottam Nagar'], 'address_2': ['Dayal Bagh'], 'mob_no': ['9087654321'], 'gender': ['Male'], 'age': ['12'], 'state': ['Uttar Pradesh'], 'city': ['Agra'], 'country': ['India'], 'bio': ['Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professo'], 'profile_pic': ['Screenshot from 2021-07-14 16-44-31.png']}>
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

edit_profile.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'todo_app:edit_profile' profile.user.id %}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="first_name">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="{{profile.user.first_name}}" name="first_name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="{{profile.user.last_name}}" name="last_name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="address_1">Address line 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_1" value="{{profile.address_line_1}}" name="address_1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="address_2">Address line 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_2" value="{{profile.address_line_2}}" name="address_2" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="mobile_no">Mobile No</label>
      <input type="number" min="6000000000" max="9999999999" value="{{profile.user.mob_no}}" class="form-control" id="mobile_no" name="mob_no" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="gender">Gender</label>
      <select class="custom-select" id="gender" name="gender" required>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>️‍</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="120" value="{{profile.age}}" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="State" class="form-label">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" name="state" value="{{profile.state}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="{{profile.city}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" value="{{profile.country}}" >
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-3">
    <label for="bio">Bio</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="bio" style="height: 100px" name="bio">{{profile.bio}}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3 ml-auto mt-4">
      <img src="{{profile.profile_pic.url}}" class="rounded-circle" width="100px" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="profile_pc_spam">Profile Pic</span>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="profile_pic"  name='profile_pic' >
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="profile_pic">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<button class="btn my_button_delete mb-4 ustify-content-center" type="submit" >Submit form</button>
</div>
</form>
```

what am I doing wrong? i don't want to use django forms.
i try to search old question related this problem on stack overflow but i found that every one suggest using django form. if i missed any answer please tag me

Comment: Hi @pysaundary, can you verify that the files are being sent to the server by observing the POST request in your browser's Developer Tools' Network panel?

Comment: no image is not showing in network panel , now what should i do?

Comment: If StackOverflow asks you to write more details to your question, you really should do it. It's not there so that you'll then add dummy text to your question.

Comment: hi @JamesZ ,thanks next time i will not do that ,and second thing language is big barrier for me for explain my problem in english

Comment: @pysaundary If the image isn't being sent along, you're not selecting a valid file, have some javascript that's removing the file from the form submission or have invalid HTML that's preventing the element from being included. However, your console output and form seem to be contradictory. Are you sure the code you've pasted is the same exact code that you ran to get those error messages?

Comment: yes code is same ,you can see that i am only get values from post and trying to print on console.because i was getting error due to empty dic in request.files then i found that no file is sending to server

Comment: hi @schillingt ,i did not use any java script

Comment: Can you confirm the generated HTML matches what you have above for the form and file elements?

Comment: @schillingt it is solved ,i just change change ="" and it is solved but now i am facing other issue ,my uploaded file is not save on right location even i can't found where it is save

Comment: Review the docs regarding the MEDIA_* settings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-root and serving files in development: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development